# syntax error, unexpected '<' < end );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ^):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

I have been receiving the above mentioned error for a couple of hours now. I am working an a broadcast screen for a ruby project which needs to have a drop down menu that is linked to a skills table. I have generated the broadcast controller, and when editing the _form.html.erb file, I have been thrown a few syntax errors, attached are snippets of my files

[image: console message]

[image: _form.html.erb]

I have tried moving the "<" around and completely out of the file but i still end up with errors.

Comment: Why don't you paste your code here instead?

Comment: Also, on line 27, do you see a missing `%` on your `end` statement?

Comment: I have added a "%" but still getting an error. My error reads:
app/views/broadcasts/_form.html.erb:27: syntax error, unexpected '<'
app/views/broadcasts/_form.html.erb:27: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
app/views/broadcasts/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_broadcasts_new_html_erb___30803597_93402384'

Comment: Don't post images unless your question is about GUI or image processing. Copy and paste your console output and code instead.

Comment: Thats not the only syntax errorr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says exactly where the problem is: `_form.html.erb:27` where `<end %>` is used.

By the way, it's not the only place, where `<% %>` pattern for `html.erb` is used incorrectly. The `<%= form.label :skill>` has no closing `%>`, that's why everything that goes after until next `%>` is treated as a `Ruby` code. The code is incorrect and raises `syntax error`

In order to avoid syntax errors, the `skill` fieldset should be rewritten into this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <%= form.label :skill %>
  <%= form.collection_select :skill, Skill.order(:name), :name, :name, include_blank: "Select skill" %>
</div>
```